# C# SQL .NET2 Web Service strange behaviour with SQLDataAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sql-server-2008

I have an intermittent issue where code that works successfully 99% of the time will occasionally return a dataset from the previous query. I've tried everything I can think of to resolve. Here's a stripped down idea of what I am doing. I'm hoping someone may have had this situation before and can advise me what's going wrong.

In the example below the data from Query1 is returned in the dataset from Query2. This code is hit roughly 30'000 times a day and I will see maybe 200-400 occurrences of this error in small batches at various times, e.g. 07:45 to 07:47 then again at 11:02 to 11:04 etc. The remaining times all works as expected. Also it occurs throughout the code and not just in one pair of queries.

My assumption is some sort of threading issue in the SQL connection pool maybe?

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] CallAuth(string szCallingPartyAddress, string szCalledPartyAddress, string szInboundTrunk, string RetryCallId, string szProvenIdentity)

{

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CKTS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Query1", sqlConnection))
                {
                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lCallId", lCallId);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nAction", nAction);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nSeconds", nSeconds);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter objSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
                    {
                        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
                        objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
                    }
                }
            }

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CKTS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Query2", sqlConnection))
                {
                    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lCallId", lCallId);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nAction", nAction);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nSeconds", nSeconds);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter objSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand))
                    {
                        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
                        objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it is the same connection string, why do you create two connections?

Comment: are you carching any error?

Comment: Adrian - there is business logic between the 2 queries, sometimes the second query is not required. The same connection is created maybe 20 times throughout the code path for this method but I thought the using statement would return the connection to the pool each time. Would you suggest having the complete method inside one using connection?

Comment: mnNets - I catch an error when I try and read the data from the dataset. This is how I discovered the data being read was not what I expected but is from the previous query

Comment: .Net is using connection pooling by itself, so I don't think it should be a problem. I thought these are two consecutive calls, so seems to me more natural to have them running in the same using block.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that's what I expected. Any ideas on the actual problem? I'm at a loss to see how data from one Dataset can turn up in another when there is no link between them